# Can the Harrier jet really take off both conventionally and vertically?

Tags: harrier

What I am able to understand from the above video, harrier jets have both capabilities:

1)To take off horizontally like other conventional aircraft like the F16 (because it has also tires)

2)To take off vertically like helicopter

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What is your confusion?  Why do you think that might not be accurate?  What research have you done to try to figure it out?

Comment: I just want to confirm, is it ocrrect that i can take off horizontally? As in most videos, i have seen it takes off vertically

Comment: The video shows one taking off horizontally.

Comment: Have you actually had a look at the video you posted? Both kind of take off are shown there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The vertical take off was more a "parlor trick", only possible with very light loading. For the most part a short or conventional takeoff was used.

> The Harrier Jump Jet, though capable of taking off vertically, can only do so at less than its maximum loaded weight. In most cases a short take off is needed to lift the required amount of fuel and weapons needed for a training sortie/mission, using forward speed to supplement the jet lift with aerodynamic lift.
> <sub>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrier_Jump_Jet)</sub>

Comment: Yes, but vertical landings were usual...

Comment: @xxavier indeed, when you've burnt off plenty of fuel and dropped all your ordnance, then it was absolutely doable.

Comment: I was at an airshow once where they said they couldn’t demonstrate pure vertical takeoffs or landings because the runway surface was tarmac and the jet blast would destroy it.

Comment: @Jim I have similar memories at farnbourough airshow in the late 90s or early 00s

Comment: V22 Osprey has the same issue

Comment: @sophit even pure helicopters can have close to the same issue, I remember a Vietnam War Huey pilot's recounting of being in that situation in his memoir (Chickenhawk). Had to basically slide on the skids for a while building up speed until they could get in the air

Comment: @llama: I meant that when the osprey is in helicopter configuration the jet blast of the turboprop can destroy the tarmac where it lands/takes off. If I remember well it cannot land/take off from all aircraft carriers just for that reason